# Where to find ammConfig address?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I'm currently experimenting with AAM Pools from Raydium. Some actions require a `ammConfigId`.

Does someone know where I can find or fetch this address?

Answer (score 0):

Use [getProgramAccounts](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getprogramaccounts) rpc request.

Comment: Of the Raydium program you mean? If yes, how can I find it for a specific pool? I assume it's a different one for each pool.